# How random number behaves in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the use of rand(INT) and what is happening when we multiply another number to that result rand(INT) * 10 or  rand(INT) * 12

What benefit do we get if we multiply some number to rand(INT)

It seems that it produces distributed number as per the number we use for multiply. In my case it is 19. 
If we give 19 then all our random numbers are never be beyond 19. Is that so?

Also, it is mentioned that `rand(seed)` produces output in deterministic way. What does it mean, and why does the value in my dataset actually varies?

```
scala> val df = hc.sql("""select 8 , rand(123456), rand(123456)*19, floor(rand(123456)*19) as random_number ,rand(1)  from v-vb.omega """)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: int, _c1: double, _c2: double, random_number: bigint, _c4: double]

scala> df.show(100,false)
 +---+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------------+
 |_c0|_c1                 |_c2                |random_number|_c4                 |
 +---+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------------+
 |8  |0.4953081723589211  |9.4108552748195    |9            |0.13385709732307427 |
|8  |0.8134447122366524  |15.455449532496395 |15           |0.5897562959687032  |
 |8  |0.37061329883387006 |7.0416526778435315 |7            |0.01540012100242305 |
 |8  |0.039605242829950704|0.7524996137690634 |0            |0.22569943461197162 |
 |8  |0.6789785261613072  |12.900591997064836 |12           |0.9207602095112212  |
 |8  |0.9696879210080743  |18.424070499153412 |18           |0.6222816020094926  |
 |8  |0.773136636564404   |14.689596094723676 |14           |0.1029837279488438  |
 |8  |0.7990411192888535  |15.181781266488215 |15           |0.6678762139023474  |
 |8  |0.8089896546054375  |15.370803437503312 |15           |0.06748208566157787 |
 |8  |0.0895536147884225  |1.7015186809800276 |1            |0.5215181769983375  |
 |8  |0.7385237395885733  |14.031951052182894 |14           |0.8895645473999635  |
|8  |0.059503458368902584|1.130565709009149  |1            |0.321509746474296   |
|8  |0.14662556746599353 |2.785885781853877  |2            |0.28823975483307396 |
|8  |0.28066416785509374 |5.332619189246781  |5            |0.45999786693699807 |
|8  |0.5563531082651644  |10.570709057038123 |10           |0.17320175842535657 |
|8  |0.6619862377687996  |12.577738517607193 |12           |1.152006730106292E-4|
|8  |0.9090845495301373  |17.272606441072607 |17           |0.7500451351287378  |
```

Comment: My question is how rand(INT) works? It is mentioned it produces output in deterministic way . What does it  mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deterministic means that function result is always the same for the same argument (Different invocations of function with the same argument produces the same result).

In your dataset it is definitely not deterministic because there are different random numbers produced with the same seed argument. If the documentation states it should be deterministic, then it is a bug in the documentation or bug in the function implementation.

Another question is why `rand(12345)*19` is never beyond 19? This is because rand values are > 0 and < 1. This I believe is as per specification

Answer (score 3):

In Spark, `rand(seed)` and `randn(seed)` are not deterministic, which is an unresolved bug. Corresponding note was added to its [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L1225) via JIRA [SPARK-13380](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13380):

```
  /**
   * Generate a random column with independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) samples
   * from U[0.0, 1.0].
   *
   * @note The function is non-deterministic in general case.
   *
   * @group normal_funcs
   * @since 1.4.0
   */
  def rand(seed: Long): Column = withExpr { Rand(seed) }
```